# String between two characters (dots)

Tags: regex, preg-match

Is there a possibility to use Regex for finding matching string between two dots?

I have strings with direcotries and I need to find string between two dots. Eg:
$string = '/Folder/file.co.txt';
and regex will return ONLY **co** between two dots.
I've tried following pattern: '/..../', but it returned **.co.** with dots.

Is there a possibility to do this with regex or all I can do is splice returned string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx - Exclude Matched Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241463/regex-exclude-matched-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$string = '/Folder/file.co.txt';
preg_match('/(?<=\.)..(?=\.)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

**Output:**

```
co
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Also thank you for link. It's very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

If you use preg_match you can set braces like () to define a group.
Your Statement can look like

```
"~\.(..)\.~g"
```